# Qt Sql query - how to get a single value from table column?

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, qt

I am trying to get a single value from table column by using WHERE and ID of selected element, but "query->value(0)" always returns 0.

```
float dbSqlQueries::selectMoviePrice(QSqlDatabase db, QTableView *tableview){

  float priceValue;
  QString FetchedID = FetchIDSelectedInTable(tableview);
  qDebug() << "MovieID"<<FetchedID;

  QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(db);
  query->prepare("SELECT rentcostperday FROM public.Movies WHERE movieid =" + FetchedID);
  query->exec();

  query->next();
  priceValue = query->value(0).toFloat();

  qDebug() <<"Selected price:"<< priceValue;
  return priceValue;}
```

```
MovieID "1"
Selected price: 0
MovieID "3"
Selected price: 0
MovieID "1"
Selected price: 0
MovieID "10"
Selected price: 0
```

Postgres query returns the correct value. How should I fix this?

Comment: In Qt to format strings itìs better to use `QString("...%1...%2").arg(arg1).arg(arg2);` this way you can control the format of the numbers. Try to print the select string on the output to be sure it's well formatted

Comment: @MarcoBeninca Thanks! This does look better and string came out well formatted, but that still haven't fixed my problem.
`"SELECT rentcostperday FROM public.Movies WHERE movieid = 1"
Selected price: 0`

Comment: the correct way to use `QSqlQuery` is not to pass the already formatted string but to use `QSqlQuery::bindValue` to pass values on the `WHERE` condition... see the examples on [Qt Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html)

Comment: @MarcoBeninca I have tried this:
`query->prepare("SELECT rentcostperday FROM public.Movies WHERE movieid = :movieid");
    query->bindValue(":movieid", FetchedID);
    query->exec();`
But the result stays the same.

Comment: I think your query doesn't select any row... What does return `QSqlQuery::numRowsAffected()` ?

Comment: @MarcoBeninca It returns `1`.  Maybe the problem is in the way I am trying to access this value? In other examles I've seen `query->next()` work just fine, don't see why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `query->next()` by`query->first()`